# Proving convergence of projected subgradient descent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convex-optimization

Any idea how to sum the series $\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} (\|x_t -a\|^2 -\|x_{t+1}-a\|^2) $, where $a$ is any constant and you can assume $\|x_{T+1}-a\|=0$. This sum occured in proving convergence of projected subgradient descent with time-varying step size.

Answer (score 0):

I have used such things before in work I've done.  We get: 
\begin{align}
&\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}(||x_t-a||^2 - ||x_{t+1}-a||^2) \\
&= ||x_1-a||^2 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}||x_{T+1}-a||^2 + \sum_{t=2}^{T}||x_t-a||^2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t-1}}\right) \\
&\leq ||x_1-a||^2 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}||x_{T+1}-a||^2
\end{align}

Comment: Hello Sir,  How could you neglect last term in the second to last equality?

Comment: The norm-squared is always non-negative, while $(1/\sqrt{t}) - (1/\sqrt{t-1})$ is negative.